# How can I find out the size of a UIScrollView's Scroll Indicator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have some content in a `UICollectionView`, which is appearing under the scroll view indicator when I scroll the collectionview. I would like the content to be inset so that it is above the scroll indicator (this is horizontal scrolling) in terms of y position, so that they do not overlap when it appears. How can I find the size of the scroll indicator of the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Officially you can't. But in actual fact, it is a subview of the UIScrollView, so you can investigate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would note that having the scroll indicator "on top of" your content (that is, rendered over your content) is exactly how it is supposed to work. That's how it works in all Apple apps, as well as nearly all 3rd-party apps as well.

That said, if you're determined to find the frame of the indicator – I'm sure you have a good reason – you can dig around in the view tree of `UIScrollView` and find the private view that represents it. If you do end up doing this, be aware that this is technically not allowed. Make sure to safeguard that code especially well against the possibility of the view not existing, being a different class between iOS versions, etc.

*Edit:* Of course, [matt beat me to it in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830849/how-can-i-find-out-the-size-of-a-uiscrollviews-scroll-indicator?#comment47788714_29830849). Thanks matt!